# Do not know how to async this

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, async.js

I  have listed everything to do with this command ive been working on and this is the error it returns with, i wanted to test if the finding pictures thing work but it just returns with

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1097:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

I do understand the problem but i do not know how to async, pls help <3

```
   const superagent = require("superagent");

bot.on('message', message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

         case 'cat':
                let message = await message.channel.send("Finding Cat Pictures...")

                let {body} = await superagent
                .get('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
                console.log(body.file)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the function `async`

```js
bot.on('message', async message => {

    let args = message.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ");

         case 'cat':
                let message = await message.channel.send("Finding Cat Pictures...")

                let {body} = await superagent
                .get('https://aws.random.cat/meow')
                console.log(body.file)
```

Comment: You're welcome, and welcome to SO, if an answer solves your question be sure to accept it using the tick mark next to it to let others know what worked and that the question has been answered

Comment: it now says, cannot access message before initialisation

 let message = await message.channel.send("Finding Cat Pictures...")    with arrows above await

Comment: Try and specify one question per question. If you have another question that's fine, but open it up as a new one, don't just dogpile on this one.